# What characters are available on the Split Screen mode?

Tags: the-grand-tour-game

I saw that The Grand Tour Game has a split screen option where you can play with friends and select a character to play with. What characters are available to pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I watched a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/AVOtiX-lqh4?t=94) of the game and at the car and character selection screen, it appears you get to choose between the main characters of the show:

- Jeremy Clarkson
- Richard Hammond
- James May
- Abbie Eaton

Comment: Well, I saw that video prior to posting the question and didn't take a look at P2 (that was scrolling between all of the characters), just at P1 (that scrolled only between Clarkson, Hammond and picked May).